# Decrypt Blowfish encrypted HSQLDB .script File

Tags: sql, encryption, hsqldb, blowfish

it's my first Question, so please don't be harsh if you're seeing any mistakes.
I'm creating an embedded HSQLDB via a Client.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:"
    + dataBaseName
    + ";crypt_key=604a6105889da65326bf35790a923932;crypt_type=blowfish;shutdown=true","sa", "");
```

It's encrypted with Blowfish. I only defined the Key. Now i want to decrypt the .script File with Notepad++ Extensions but it asks for an IV-Key and the Salt. I haven't defined these Arguments but i need them.
Any Suggestions?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it directly.

Connect to the database via any client. Then use the command below for the name and location for saving the .script file in non-encrypted format.

```
 SCRIPT 'path/filename'
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, it works perfectly. Another Question: Could the Script File be saved with another password? My new Client which should use the new .script File uses a different crypt Key. The connection to an un-encrypted Database (script File) cannot simply be established. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You create an empty encrypted database with new crypt key, You then execute the SQL in the .script file on the new database using SqlTool.

Comment: Thanks again for your Help!! It works but if i load the uncompressed decrypted .script in the DB Manager and press execute SQL there appear a few Failures (a view Lines). How could that be? I got a lot of .script Files and it would take me a lot of time to manually search for the mistakes.

Comment: I said using SqlTool which is a separate jar.

Comment: I did that, that caused failures.

Comment: The lines that are necessary are those with CREATE and INSERT INTO but not the SYSTEM_LOBS. You can ignore errors caused by other lines.